# Problem with multiple threads call in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, lambda

I have a script that has two threads, a worker thread that is running this target function:

```
def worker_thread_function():
    print(f'Worker thread started.')
    while self._keep_running:
        try:
            task = worker_queue.get(timeout=5)
            task() # I expect to be callables.
            worker_queue.task_done() # See https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html
        except queue.Empty:
            continue
    print(f'Worker thread finished.')
```

where `worker_queue` is a global object in which other "administrative threads" put stuff that has to be done. The other thread is periodically putting stuff in this queue in this way:

```
def other_thread_function():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        for device_name in devices_df.index: # Initialize this by logging once each device.
            if has_to_be_logged(device_name):
                print(f'Now queueing for log {device_name}')
                worker_queue.put(lambda: log_single_device_standby_IV(device_name))
```

and the function `log_single_device_standby_IV` does stuff with that device name. The problem I am facing is that `device_name` has the correct value when queuing the task, but the wrong value when the task is done. If I put a print inside the `log_single_device_standby_IV` like this:

```
def log_single_device_standby_IV(device_name)
    print(f'log_single_device_standby_IV({device_name})')
    # do the stuff...
```

in my output I see this:

```
Now queueing for log num5
log_single_device_standby_IV(num7) was called.
Now queueing for log num11
log_single_device_standby_IV(num7) was called.
Now queueing for log num5
log_single_device_standby_IV(num7) was called.
```

i.e. it somehow changes whatever value has `device_name` by `num7`. The device `num7` is casually the last one in `devices_df.index`, don't know if this may provide any hint of what is going on. If I hardcode the device name like this:

```
def other_thread_function():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        for device_name in devices_df.index: # Initialize this by logging once each device.
            if has_to_be_logged(device_name):
                worker_queue.put(lambda: log_single_device_standby_IV('num4'))
```

it works fine, i.e. it uses `num4` as device name.

What is the problem here? I don't know if it has to do with having multiple threads, with the lambda function, or what...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [late-binding closures](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) across threads.  And you should be able to correct it using `functools.partial`.

Instead of:

```
worker_queue.put(lambda: log_single_device_standby_IV(device_name))
```

use

```
worker_queue.put(functools.partial(log_single_device_standby_IV, device_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

After asking this question and spending quite an amount of time thinking that this was a threads related problem, I found that the issue was with the lambda function. Changing the line with the lambda function to

```
worker_queue.put(lambda dev=device_name: self.log_single_device_standby_IV(dev))
```

solves the problem.

So the issue was that the lambda function was not storing the value of `device_name` but a reference to it.